# return raw binary ipv4 GET repsonse in elixir

Tags: http, binary, elixir, packet, ipv4

I'm aware of the existence of libraries that return HTTP responses as `struct`s:

```erlang
> HTTPoison.get!("http://httpbin.org/get")
> %HTTPoison.Response{body: "{\n  \"args\": {}, \n  \"headers\": {\n   \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", \n    \"User-Agent\": \"hackney/1.6.6\"\n  }, \n  \"origin\": \"86.30.176.31\", \n  \"url\": \"http://httpbin.org/get\"\n}\n", headers: [{"Server", "nginx"}, {"Date", "Sun, 12 Mar 2017 06:05:29 GMT"},{"Content-Type", "application/json"}, {"Content-Length", "165"}, {"Connection", "keep-alive"}, {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"}, {"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"}], status_code: 200}
```

However how do I get the raw `binary` form of a ipv4 HTTP response packet in elixir?

As per Dogbert's suggestion, I tried using `gen_tcp`, but got the following:

```erlang
iex(1)> {:ok, port} = :gen_tcp.connect('httpbin.org',80,[:binary, active: 
false, packet: :http])
{:ok, #Port<0.6531>}
iex(2)> :gen_tcp.send(port, "GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\n")
:ok
iex(3)> :gen_tcp.recv(port,0)
{:error, :closed}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If the request is a simple GET, you can use `gen_tcp` directly. If it's more complex, I believe [`hackney`](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney) must have an option to get the raw response but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: If it's just for debugging purposes, maybe [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) would be a good general-purpose option for you?

Comment: @PatrickOscity - tried that, however I'm looking for something I can reproduce in elixir.

Comment: @Dogbert I'm going to update the question with my `gen_tcp` attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the `packet: :http` option in `gen_tcp.connect` and adding another `\r\n` at the end of the HTTP text solved it:

```erlang
iex(3)> {:ok, packet_binary} = :gen_tcp.recv(port,0)
{:ok, {:http_response, {1, 1}, 200, 'OK'}}

iex(4)> {:ok, port} = :gen_tcp.connect('httpbin.org',80,[:binary, active: false])               
{:ok, #Port<0.6706>}

iex(5)> :gen_tcp.send(port, "GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\n\r\n")    
:ok

iex(6)> {:ok, packet_binary} = :gen_tcp.recv(port,0)                             
{:ok,
 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: nginx\r\nDate: Sun, 12 Mar 2017 14:01:05 GMT\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 129\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\r\n\r\n{\n  \"args\": {}, \n  \"headers\": {\n    \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\"\n  }, \n  \"origin\": \"86.30.176.31\", \n  \"url\": \"http://httpbin.org/get\"\n}\n"}

iex(7)> IO.puts(packet_binary)  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 12 Mar 2017 14:01:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 129
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "origin": "86.30.176.31", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}

:ok

iex(8)> is_binary(packet_binary)
true
```

Comment: hmmm actually I'm not to sure about this - I need to verify that's an ipv4 packet - doesn't seem to fit the ipv4 spec.